# Error in reading values from XML file

Tags: java, xml

I am trying to read values from a XML file but I am getting `null` values while I am trying to print them into the console. I am giving my code here and also the XML file.

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<customer id="1"
   age="29"
   name="jeet">
 </customer>
```

**Model Class**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Customer {

    String name;
    int age;
    int id;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

**Driver**

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

public class CheckClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File file = new File("./file/NewFile.xml");
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            Customer customer = (Customer) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
            System.out.println(customer.age);
            System.out.println(customer.name);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

`System.out.println(customer.age);`
`System.out.println(customer.name);` Giving me `0` and `null` values.

Could somebody please help, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is caused because your java code is expecting does not match with that XML structure. You have two options:

Change the annotations `@XmlElement` to `@XmlAttribute`

or

Change your xml to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<customer id="1">
   <age>29</age>
   <name>jeet</name>
 </customer>
```

Comment: i can not change the XML style the structure will be the same

Comment: Then use the first option: change the annotations

Answer (score 0):

name and age are attribute not element. Try this:

```
@XmlAttribute
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@XmlAttribute
public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use 
[Xstream library](http://xstream.codehaus.org/)

Example:

```
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.XStreamAlias;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.XStreamAsAttribute;

@XStreamAlias("Cat")
class Cat {
  @XStreamAsAttribute
  int age;
  String name;
}

public class XStreamDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        XStream xstream = new XStream();
        xstream.processAnnotations(Cat.class);

        String xml = "<Cat age='4' ><name>Garfield</name></Cat>";

        Cat cat = (Cat) xstream.fromXML(xml);

        System.out.println("name -> " + cat.name);
        System.out.println("age -> " + cat.age);

    }

}
```

You need to add Xstream jar files in to classpath.

Comment: xstream is not the issue here